# Kibana Dashboard instead of my application dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, integration, kibana, kibana-6

Is it possible to integrate Kibana dashboard in my application instead of my application dashboard, that means when you click on dashboard tab it should open Kibana dashboard.

Comment: Hi. It's been a while since I posted my answer. Would you consider accepting my answer if it helped you? I would really appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can! :-)

Just open your particular Dashboard in Kibana and you should see a "Share"-Button like in the following figure.

[image]

You can decide between an HTML iFrame snippet (Embedded code) or an URL (Permalink) to your dashboard. Note the difference between Saved Objects and Snapshots:

Snapshots will only display the data at the time you take the snapshot, hence any updated data will not be displayed.
Saved objects on the other hand can be seen as references to the dashboard itself and will have the most recent data.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it, should open your Dashboard and use the 'Share'button.
Hope you could fix it.